# AWS Lambda test event -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have the below lambda function code with GET httpmethod and trying to get an item from DynamoDB. Using AWS SDK v3
function snippet-

```js
const {httpMethod, body, pathParameters} = event;
const {id} = pathParameters;

if (httpMethod === 'GET') {
  // READ operation
  const params = {
    TableName: 'Emp_Basic',
    Key: {id}
  };
  const command = new GetItemCommand(params);
  const result = await dynamoDBClient.send(command);

  if (!result.Item) {
    return {
      statusCode: 404,
      body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Item not found'})
    };
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(result.Item)
  };
}
```

Ideally the item inside dynamodb should be returned. Not able to figure out whats causing this issue

Comment: Try: `Key: { id: { S: id } }` if `client` is the usual `DynamoDBClient` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code indicates the `Key` attribute value incorrectly, as:

```
Key: { id }
```

Instead, it needs to indicate both the name and the type of the key attribute, as well as its value, specifically:

```
Key: { id: { S: id } }
```

That indicates the attribute name of `id` and the type of `S` (string).